# Unable to add new row to exisitng table in word document using WordprocessingDocument

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a word document in which there is table added. I want to access that document and add new blank row to the table which is already in it. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622489/add-a-row-to-an-existing-table-in-a-word-document-open-xml) reference link and created below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = "C:\\TestDoc1.docx";
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);

        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
        {
            Body bod = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            foreach (Table t in bod.Descendants<Table>().Where(tbl => tbl.GetFirstChild<TableRow>().Descendants<TableCell>().Count() == 4))
            {
                // Create a row.
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                t.Append(tr);
            }

        }
        // Save the file with the new name
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\TestDoc2.docx", stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

However, code does not throw any error. But when I open TestDoc2.docx I am getting the below error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a code plex helper dll which is fast, lightweight and it does not require Microsoft Word or Office to be installed. You can get that from [here](https://docx.codeplex.com/). Add reference of this dll to your solution and write below code:

```
using(DocX doc = DocX.Load(filePath))
{
    // you can use whatever condition you would like to select the table from that table.
   // I am using the Title field value in the Table Properties wizard under Alter Text tab 
    Novacode.Table t = doc.Tables.Cast<Table>().FirstOrDefault(tbl => tbl.TableCaption == "Test");
    Row r = t.InsertRow();
    doc.SaveAs("C:\\TestDoc2.docx");
}
```

It works like a charm in my case!!! :-)

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

What was missing in your first code was a TableCell and a Paragraph

```
// Create a row.
TableRow tr = new TableRow(new TableCell(new Paragraph()));
t.Append(tr);
```

A TableRow must at least contain one TableCell and a TableCell must contain a Paragraph